# Generate Oracle database objects

Tags: database, oracle, object, scripting

Is there any functionality within Oracle to generate deployment scripts given a defined set of database objects.  I'm thinking of functionality similar to the SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard, which when provided with the desired objects, it will go away and generate a script (accommodating dependencies).  I know SQL Developer along with most of the other (pay-for) tools are able to do this but I wondered if there was anything out of the box (that comes with Oracle) that provides this facility.

Comment: Your deployment scripts should not be "reverse engineered", they should be stored in a version control system and any change should only be done through them.

Answer (score 0):

It would actually be a combination of a script to capture all of your objects using the technique described in this previous question: [How to programmatically generate DDL from Oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160865/how-to-programmatically-generate-ddl-from-oracle-database)

Basically, you use dbms_metadata.get_ddl to generate the object ddl.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an export of the database schema (with or without any table data) using [Data Pump Export](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#g1022624).
Disadvantage is, the export file is not a human readable script, but in general it works.

Answer (score 0):

we can use oracle export utility to generate ddl scripts without data option, which is available as a backward compatibility in latest oracle versions.