# Finding the actual script of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I look at the actual script of a stored procedure in Oracle database?

I used the following command to see if it exists and it does but now I need to look at the script in order to analyze it:

```
select * from ALL_OBJECTS where OBJECT_NAME like 'P_CREATE_FILES';
```

I am using SQL developer.

Comment: Use something like TOAD or Sql Developer.

Comment: use `ALL_SOURCE`

Comment: I assume you mean the DDL, right? A number of people have posted questions related to obtaining the DDL. Take a look at this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160865/how-to-programmatically-generate-ddl-from-oracle-database

Comment: @DanBracuk I am using SQL developer.

Comment: @KaushikNayak How can I use ALL_SOURCE to find the stored procedure?

Comment: @PatrickBacon I just want to read the store procedure .

Comment: If you are using SQL Developer, connect to the database and look at the menu on the left.

Comment: Is it just a plain procedure or a package procedure? Packages, by their nature, make it harder to get at the source. Do you have the required permissions to view this source?

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Developer, open the stored procedure. See the CODE tab.

[image]

If the stored procedure belongs to a schema other than the user you're logged in as, go to the Other Users node in the tree, expand it, select your user, then select your stored procedure.

You could also run

```
select text
 from all_source
 where owner = 'HR' and name = 'ADD_JOB_HISTORY'
 order by line asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could query the `ALL_SOURCE` table

```
SELECT text 
  FROM all_source
 WHERE owner = 'USERA'
   AND name  = 'PROCA'
 ORDER BY line;
```

For a procedure inside a package

```
SELECT text 
  FROM all_source
 WHERE owner = 'USERA'
   AND name  = 'PROCA'
   AND type  = 'PACKAGE BODY'
 ORDER BY line;
```